# Как перенести автозамены из punto switcher в Espanso для linux?

Tags: linux, sublime-text

Мне нужно открыть файлы, которые находятся в `punto switcher`, но при открытии через редактор `sublime text`  отображает какие то цифры, допустим как в файле `replace.dat`. А мне нужен текст , автозапрос сокращенный, и полный текст.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]